# Handling null response from server

Tags: angular

I have a ngIf condition to check the response data. I am getting a null response when there is no data. I want to show "No data Found " if it's null. I tried `ngIf="!addresses"` But it's not working how do I handle this? 
Template:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 *ngIf="(!addresses )">  

              <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"> 
               No Data Found  

            </div>
          </div>
```

Component:

```
getData(id){

        this.service.GetData(id)
        .subscribe(addresses => this.addresses = addresses)
        this.OnceHttp = !this.OnceHttp;
        }
```

Response : 
`Null` 
Service:

```
GetData(id){
                const eurl='http://localhost/Angular/GetData.php?id='
                const url= `${eurl}${id}`
                return this.http.get(url)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.HandleError)

            }
```

I am getting a null value from the server. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong??

Comment: What is the code of this.dataservice.Getaddress method?

Comment: What do you mean by null reponse when no data? Your backend returns a 400+ response or just an empty response?

Comment: Just empty response.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You could define an `empty` property in your component as follows:

```
getAddress(id){
    this.dataservice.Getaddress(id)
    .subscribe(addresses => this.addresses = addresses);
    this.OnceHttp = !this.OnceHttp;
    }

get empty(){
   return this.addresses === null || this.addresses.length === 0;
}
```

Then you could use the get property in your template as

```
<div *ngIf="empty">//code to show when addresses has no content</div>
```

Comment: If there is no data then there i should show "No data found" . i am not able to handle response Null .

Comment: Updated my answer, I think I misunderstood your question

Comment: Its not working. .length does not exist on address.  and without it, it's not working.

Comment: I thought addresses was an array because of the name. What is the type of it? I would now assume that it is an object because of the definition of your service method url getAddress. If thats the case, you should just make a null check

Comment: I changed the output when null to `{error: "No"}` Now i get this as output when null. How can i use this array now??

Answer (score 0):

Remove `hidden` from your outermost div:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 hidden margin-top" id="blank-skills" 
     *ngIf="!addresses">
```

I would though do a null check and instead of `!addresses` check if addresses `== null`, but that is just my opinion :)

Without the `hidden`, it should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/3bKTBjkiQHdBZmnqyhRi?p=preview

Comment: What if i get a response like `{error: "NoData"}`. When it is null. How can i handle this?

Comment: I removed hidden. and tried it. Its not working . :( I tried == null too. Still its not working

Comment: Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker?